# Factorial of $i$

Tags: complex-numbers

With $i^2=-1$, what is $i!$ ?

I'm not sure if it is $i$ or if it is an infinite product $i(i-1)(i-2)(i-3)(i-4)(i-5)\dots$

It would make sense either way.

Is it not defined?

Comment: Have you heard about the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)? It is the usual way of interpreting factorials for general complex numbers. For instance [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i%21) interprets $i!$ as $\Gamma(i + 1)$.

Comment: Yes I would say look into the gamma function as it probably holds the key to your problem. It can be represented as an infinite product or as an integral. It can also pop out in other situations...

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

$$\Gamma(i+1) \approx 0.498015668 - 0.154949828\, i $$