# what is the value of i factorial using the complex number system?

Tags: complex-numbers, factorial, gamma-function

what is the value of i factorial? "I" belongs to the complex number system. Thanks for helping me out with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Gamma function gives
$$
\Gamma (1+i)=i\Gamma (i)\approx 0.498-0.155i
$$
However, only for integers we have $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$. Nevertheless one may view this as a generalization of factorial. The question has already been answered in great detail in this sense [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-i-factorial). There is also a duplicate at MSE:

[Factorial of $i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015928/factorial-of-i)

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, the factorial of "$\text{a non-negative integer}$" $n$, denoted by $n!$, is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$.

That is, $n\in \textbf Z$ only. It is not defined for complex numbers. Complex numbers are out of the factorial function's domain.

I hope this helped you. Cheers!!

Comment: Some definitions of the factorial allow complex arguments, using the identity $z!:=\Gamma(z+1)$.